# multiprocessing.Pool.apply_async on Windows

Tags: python, windows, multiprocessing, pool

I'm trying to use a pool to farm out some subprocess calls in parallel. Everything works fine if I construct an entire iterable for the the pool and use `imap`, `map`, `imap_unordered`, etc. but I can't get `apply_async` to work.

For example, this works correctly:

```
from subprocess import check_call
from multiprocessing import Pool

def dispatch_call(file_name):
    return check_call(...)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    files = (constructed file list)
    pool = Pool()
    pool.imap(dispatch_call, files)
    pool.close()
    pool.join()
```

This, however, does not:

```
from subprocess import check_call
from multiprocessing import Pool

def dispatch_call(file_name):
    return check_call(...)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    files = (constructed file list)
    pool = Pool()
    for f in files:
        pool.apply_async(dispatch_call, f)
    pool.close()
    pool.join()
```

I checked the docs for `multiprocessing`, and none of the Windows specific issues seem to be relevant here. Am I just out of luck trying to get this to work on Windows?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shoud pass the callback arguments as a sequence (list / tuple).

`str` object is also a sequence, but passing a string cause passing multiple arguments to the callback (each character of the string is treated as argument):

```
pool.apply_async(dispatch_call, [f])
```

OR

```
pool.apply_async(dispatch_call, (f,))
```